# Why does git rebase --onto not move any commits?

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

I have a setup that looks like this:

```
- A - B - C - ... - D - E <- copy-of-master
   \ 
     F - ... - G - H <- dev
                \ 
                 I - J <- bugfix
```

I want to move commits I and J onto `copy-of-master`, which is just a copy of `upstream1/master`.

However the command `git rebase --onto copy-of-master dev bugfix` does nothing at all. When I go to open the pull request it says that `bugfix` and `upstream1/master` are identical.

Also, after running the rebase, when I `git checkout dev` it tells me that:

> Your branch and 'upstream2/dev' have diverged,
>   and have 1814 and 1799 different commits each, respectively

Which just suggests that `dev` got moved to point at `copy-of-master` somehow, as `upstream1/master` and `upstream2/dev` are roughly 2000 commits apart.

Comment: try rebase with `--interactive` option to see what git is going to rebase, helps to troubleshoot

Comment: I'm just guessing (see my comment on VonC's answer) but I think you left out the final `bugfix` and were on `dev`, or swapped `dev` and `bugfix`, when you entered the `git rebase` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However the command `git rebase --onto copy-of-master dev bugfix` does nothing at all

That is expected:

A git rebase onto `copy-of-master dev bugfix` will move all commit AFTER `dev`, up to `bugfix`.

And in your diagram, there is no commit *after* `dev` (`H`).

```
- A - B - C - ... - D - E <- copy-of-master
   \ 
     F - ... - G - H <- dev
                \ 
                 I - J <- bugfix
```

`G` (that is `dev~1`, one commit before `dev`) however would work just fine: all commits *after* `G` up to `bugfix` do represent the `bugfix` commits.

```
git rebase --onto copy-of-master dev~1 bugfix
```

That would work, assuming `dev~1` (or `G`) is the commit from which `bugfix` branch was forked from `dev`.

Comment: This doesn't seem right: `git rebase --onto <newbase> <upstream> <branch>` means that `copy-of-master` is the `<newbase>`, `dev` is the `<upstream>`, and `bugfix` is the `<branch>`.  `rebase` will first check out `bugfix` and then find commits to rebase with `git rev-list dev..HEAD`, which should select commits `I` and `J` for copying.  It should then cherry-pick those two with `E` as the parent for `I'`, and set branch `bugfix` to point to `J'`.  I suspect a typo in the OP's commands...

Comment: @torek That is possible. I only use `rebase --onto` by specifying the exact commit I need (here the `G` commit, not `H` or `dev`)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to move commits I and J onto copy-of-master, which is just a copy of upstream1/master.

Why not simply using `git cherry-pick I J` instead?

```
git checkout copy-of-master
git cherry-pick I J
```

---

#### `git cherry-pick <SHA-1> <SHA-1> <SHA-1> ...`

> Apply the change introduced by the commit at the tip of the master branch and create a new commit with this change.

You could also specify a range for the cherry-pick

```
git cherry-pick <SHA-1>...<SHA-1>
```

[image]

Comment: That works, and is what I ended up doing, but I wanted to understand why rebase didn't do what I expected.

Comment: rebate change the existing history while cherry-pick add new commits to it